# Generating height map with Rep Rap

Tags: reprap

I recently did a G29 (run mesh calibration) and my printer did a 25 point probe and reported back the stats to the console.  After this I went to the height map section and it says "height map not available" and no stats can be used here.

So I tried to load the height map using G29 S1 and am getting:

`G29 S1 Error: G29: Failed to load height map from file heightmap.csv: Could not find file '/opt/dsf/sd/sys/heightmap.csv'`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Below is info about my control board and firmware.

RepRapFirmware for Duet 3 MB6HC version 3.1.1 running on Duet 3 MB6HC v1.01 or later (SBC mode)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an older question but thought that I would post anyway in case someone else stumbles upon this question like I just did.

An ownership change to the `/opt/dsf/sd/sys` directory can create a situation where heightmap files are unable to be saved. There are a couple of ways to check.

How to check - Method 1: Try creating a new config file from the GUI (under the same menu as your config.g file, same area where the heightmap file is supposed to be saved). If there are any issues creating or saving the file, it is a good indicator that the dir ownership has changed.

How to check - Method 2: Open a terminal and run `stat /opt/dsf/sd/sys`. There should be an area that lists the ownership and both areas (user and group) should list `dsf` as the owner. If the owner is `pi` (standard default user) or anything else then this is likely the issue.

Solution: To reset the folder ownership back to the correct setting, open a terminal and run `sudo chown -R dsf:dsf /opt/dsf/sd/sys`.

NOTE: If you found that the underlying issue is folder ownership, it is also worth checking the other directories under the `/opt/dsf/sd` path and the other directories and update with the correct permission fix where necessary.

Comment: Even though I have no way of checking this, this looks like a good answer. Hi and welcome, BTW... :-)